# SVG icons in Leaflet.js map

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I have a working Leaflet map but cannot pass in SVG icons using encodeURI (have not tried encodeURIComponent because I'm not sure that is the issue).  The [gist](https://gist.github.com/clhenrick/6791bb9040a174cd93573f85028e97af) I'm using shows how to pass in SVG rectangles and this works:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <rect> x='0' y='0' width='20' height='10' fill='#000000' </rect> </svg>
```

However, I cannot pass in a circle or a path successfully, even though the code is valid, optimized in SVGOMG, and appearing properly on SVG linters such as SVG Viewer. For example, a star.

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='50px' height='50px'><path d='M2,111 h300 l-242.7,176.3 92.7,-285.3 92.7,285.3 z' fill='#000000'/></svg>
```

An [example is on CodePen](https://codepen.io/adelaide01/pen/EXMwbY) and the relevant lines of code are:

```
var svgicon ="<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='50px' height='50px'><path d='M2,111 h300 l-242.7,176.3 92.7,-285.3 92.7,285.3 z' fill='#000000'/></svg>"

var url = encodeURI("data:image/svg+xml," + svgicon).replace(/%20/g, ' ').replace(/%22/g, "'").replace(/%3C/g,'<').replace(/%3E/g,'>');
console.log(url);
```

You can see the SVG path in the console.

```
"data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='50px' height='50px'><path d='M2,111 h300 l-242.7,176.3 92.7,-285.3 92.7,285.3 z' fill='#000000'/></svg>"
```

Nothing shows up and there is no error message. Sometimes, a broken image link shows up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you display that svg in a browser? I don't think the SVG path is well formed.

You define a 50(px) x 50(px) svg canvas.

```
<path d="
M2,111
h300
l-242.7,176.3
   92.7,-285.3
   92.7,285.3
Z
" fill="#000"/>
```

You start the path with an absolute (**M**)ove declaration at 2,111 which is outside of the canvas. Followed by a relative (**h**)orizontal line 300 to the right.
Then relative (**l**)ines -242.7,176.3 92.7,-285.3 92.7,285.3 before you clo(**Z**)e the path.

If I set the canvas to 1000 * 1000 I see this icon in the browser. Is this what you would like to see?

[image]

I draw this in LeafletJS like so:

```
let achenSvgString = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1000' height='1000'><path d='M2,111 h300 l-242.7,176.3 92.7,-285.3 92.7,285.3 z' fill='#000000'/></svg>"
let myIconUrl = encodeURI("data:image/svg+xml," + achenSvgString).replace('#','%23');

// L.icon({
//     iconUrl: myIconUrl,
//     iconSize: 40
// });
```

I didn't adjust the size as I just hammered this into a working bit of code but you can see the stars drawing here...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought I verified my SVG path was working in  http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.htm but it seems that I just need to have a better understanding of basic SVG.